# How I can know audio/video duration before uploading?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio, video

I need to upload file (audio/video) using default `input type='file'` and the I should pass duration of the video in api request, how i ca do this?

```
  const uploadFile = async (event) => {
    let file = await event.target.files[0];
    //here api POST request where i should pass duration
   }:
```

Comment: Simply create a blob URL and append this into some virtual tag, once meta data will be loaded you can get the duration and pass it to your api request.

Comment: @ShubhamPrajapat I'll be very grateful if you make me an example.

Comment: Sure, will share in few minutes.

Comment: Just posted an answer.

Comment: @ShubhamPrajapat unfortunately in returns NaN

Comment: Please share a screenshot or the error, on my end this demo works fine.
https://ji3j8.csb.app/

Comment: @ShubhamPrajapat https://prnt.sc/10aeuvd

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229345/discussion-between-shubham-prajapat-and-wefwef-efwef).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the audio duration with [HTMLMediaElement.duration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/duration):

```
async function getDuration(file) {
 const url = URL.createObjectURL(file);

 return new Promise((resolve) => {
   const audio = document.createElement("audio");
   audio.muted = true;
   const source = document.createElement("source");
   source.src = url; //--> blob URL
   audio.preload= "metadata";
   audio.appendChild(source);
   audio.onloadedmetadata = function(){
      resolve(audio.duration)
   };
 });
}
```

Then in your function:

```
const uploadFile = async (event) => {
   let file = event.target.files[0];
    //here api POST request where i should pass duration
   const duration = await getDuration(file);
 }:
```

Comment: it returns NaN and 
blob:https://localhost:3000/7c9c2321-60a3-40ee-a35e-f8b327d71851:1

Comment: yes, you need to add preload="metadata" property

Comment: where i can add this? Because i have not audio/video tag on the page

Comment: I updated my answer, as official docs says " If no media data is available, the value NaN is returned", but listening for onloadedmetadata function fix the problem

Answer (score 2):

You just need to create an element based on user input(video/audio) and get the duration property -

```js
const VIDEO = "video",
        AUDIO = "audio";
      const uploadApiCall = (file, data = {}) => {
        // ----- YOUR API CALL CODE HERE -----
        document.querySelector("#duration").innerHTML = `${data.duration}s`;
        document.querySelector("#type").innerHTML = data.type;
      };

      let inputEl = document.querySelector("#fileinput");
      inputEl.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
        let fileType = "";
        let file = inputEl.files[0];
        if (file.type.startsWith("audio/")) {
          fileType = AUDIO;
        } else if (file.type.startsWith("video/")) {
          fileType = VIDEO;
        } else {
          alert("Unsupported file");
          return;
        }

        let dataURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        let el = document.createElement(fileType);
        el.src = dataURL;
        el.onloadedmetadata = () => {
          uploadApiCall(file, {
            duration: el.duration,
            type: fileType
          });
        };
      });
```

```html
 <form>
      <input type="file" accept="video/*,audio/*" id="fileinput" />
      <hr />
      Type:<span id="type"></span>
      <br />
      Duration:<span id="duration"></span>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Vue 3 JS, I had to create a function first:

```
const getDuration = async (file) => {
      const url = URL.createObjectURL(file);

      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        const audio = document.createElement("audio");
        audio.muted = true;
        const source = document.createElement("source");
        source.src = url; //--> blob URL
        audio.preload = "metadata";
        audio.appendChild(source);
        audio.onloadedmetadata = function(){
            resolve(audio.duration)
        };
      });
    }
```

The user would select an MP3 file. Then when it was submitted I could call that function in the Submit function:

```
    const handleAudioSubmit = async () => {
      console.log('Your Epsiode Audio is being stored... please stand by!')
      if (file.value) {

        // returns a number that represents audio seconds
        duration.value = await getDuration(file.value)

        // remove the decimals by rounding up
        duration.value = Math.round(duration.value)
        console.log("duration: ", duration.value)

        // load the audio file to Firebase Storage using a composable function
        await uploadAudio(file.value)
    
        .then((downloadURL) => {
          // composable function returns Firebase Storage location URL
          epAudioUrl.value = downloadURL
        })

        .then(() => {
          console.log("uploadAudio function finished")
        })

        .then(() => {
          // Set the Album Fields based on the album id to Firestore DB
          const updateAudio = doc(db, "artist", artistId.value, "albums, albumID.value);
          updateDoc(updateAudio, {
            audioUrl: audioUrl.value,
            audioDuration: duration.value
          })
          console.log("Audio URL and Duration added to Firestore!")
        })
        .then(() => {
          console.log('Episode Audio has been added!')
          router.push({ name: 'Next' })
        })
      } else {
        file.value = null
        fileError.value = 'Please select an audio file (MP3)'
      }
    }
```

This takes some time to run and needs refactoring, but works provided you allow the async functions the time to finish. Hope that helps!